# Calling member functions of a class before class declaration

Tags: c++, function, scope, member

I am defining a macro before a class declaration. The macro calls a member function of the class. My sample code is below.

Sample class declaration,

```
// sample.h

#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define CALCULATETEMP(a, b, c) {
int d = Sample::getTempIncrement(a,b,c);
stringstream ss;
ss << d;
cout << ss.str() << endl;
}

class Sample {
public:
    Sample();
    int getTempIncrement(int a, int b, int c);
    ~Sample();
};
```

Sample class implementation,

```
//sample.cpp

#include "sample.h"
Sample::Sample() {
}

int Sample::getTempIncrement(int a, int b, int c) {
    int temp = 5;
    int d = (a*temp) + (b+c)*temp;
    return d;
}

Sample::~Sample() {
}
```

Main routine,

```
//main.cpp

#include "sample.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;
    CALCULATETEMP(a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the main.cpp, I am getting an error in sample.h file within the macro definition: "Sample" is not a class or namespace name.

How can I call a member function of the class outside the scope of the class and before the class declaration? I am quite new to programming, your feedback would help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a macro to span multiple lines, you have to put `\` at the end of each line:

```
#define CALCULATETEMP(a, b, c) {         \
int d = Sample::getTempIncrement(a,b,c); \
stringstream ss;                         \
ss << d;                                 \
cout << ss.str() << endl;                \
}
```

Also, why don't you just use a function for this (and not use `stringstream`)?

```
class Sample {
public:
    Sample();
    int getTempIncrement(int a, int b, int c);
    ~Sample();
};

void calctemp(int a, int b, int c) {
    int d = Sample::getTempIncrement(a,b,c);
    stringstream ss;
    ss << d;
    cout << ss.str() << endl; // why are you using stringstream? It could be
                              // just cout << d << endl;
}
```

Comment: yeah, 'stringstream' was some overhead there, thanks. I was just trying macros, nothing specific about not doing it with a function.

Comment: @capricorn_heitus OK, nothing wrong with experimenting :) I just wanted to point it out in case this was real code somewhere.

Comment: And remember, don't leave any whitespace after the '\' or you'll end up with the same problem.  It'll escape the space rather than any newlines.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there's another problem, as well. Sample::getTempIncrement() isn't declared as a static, so you'll need a Sample instance available in the macro.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `CALCULATETEMP(a,b,c)` to be replaced by the preprocessor with `{` and then followed it with a bunch of global space coding, which is quite illegal.

I would suggest going back to the tutorial on preprocessor macros and/or reading up on inline functions.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me some information on global space coding, I didn't get the term.

Comment: @capricorn_heitus he means that because the macro is only on that first line, the compiler takes it that you are trying to do calculations outside a function (at the _top-level_ of the file, like you can do in Python or whatever) which you can't do in C++. That and you have a stray `}`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie thanks, I got it now. So, the solution to this was your answer about spanning macros to multiple lines with ´\´ , which makes the calculations within the macro definition, right?

Comment: @capricorn_heitus precisely. The `\ ` just makes the compiler ignore the newline that comes after the `\ `.